# Get bash prompt after ssh with heredoc with no tty

Tags: bash, ssh, tty, heredoc

I would like to ssh onto a remote machine, automatise some code execution with heredoc and then provide the user with a bash prompt to manually execute further commands as needed.

So far I tried (option 1)

```
ssh user@host << 'EOF'
echo "Hello"
EOF
```

This prints out "Hello" just fine, but closes the ssh connection and exits the script. Also I get the infamous "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Same result with a single -t switch.

Next I tried (option 2)

```
ssh -tt user@host << 'EOF'
echo "Hello `uname -n`"
EOF
```

Which does the job, but produces a set of weird outputs:

```
Success. Logging you in...
echo "Hello"
echo "Hello"
[remote]$ echo "Hello"
Hello
[remote]$ <
```

Tried without using heredoc, like

```
ssh user@host 'echo "Hello"; /bin/bash'
```

but the echo will be executed on a different shell

So far, option 2 got me the closest. Any other solutions would be welcome!

Comment: Maybe something like `ssh -t user@host <<< "commands; exec bash"` will work. Cannot try at the moment.

Comment: See [Run Remote ssh command with Full Login Shell](https://superuser.com/q/306530/652023).

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting some ssh options on the command line. These can also be set in the user's ~/.ssh/config file. Replace remote-host with user@host or equivalent ssh config *Host* pattern.

single line

```sh
ssh -o RequestTTY='yes' -o RemoteCommand='echo "Hello $(uname -n)"; bash -l' remote-host
```

multiple lines

```sh
ssh -o RequestTTY='yes' -o RemoteCommand='
echo "hello from $(uname -n)"
echo "I am $(whoami)"
bash -l
' remote-host
```