# Specifying different roots for SSH and SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot, sshd

Is there a way to set up a `ChrootDirectory` for a system only for SFTP and not for ssh?

i.e. if I wanted to ssh into a server and have root be a certain directory, but SFTP into the same server and have a different directory as root, is that possible? I have been trying to toggle `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make this work but it has not been successful yet. I do not have sudo access so I cannot add another user, so this would have to be on the same user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

To have an alternate working directory after logging in with sftp, the path can be appended with a colon. Replace remote-host with user@host or ssh config *Host* pattern.

```sh
sftp remote-host:relative/path
```

or

```sh
sftp remote-host:/absolute/path
```

For similar behavior with ssh, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468277/get-bash-prompt-after-ssh-with-heredoc-with-no-tty/68470268#68470268).